# One Common submit button for two html files

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have two html and two different controller files and my requirement is i should display one common submit button for both the forms and it should be disabled until the mandatory fields are entered in both the forms.Here is the attached plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/RAzfWZYuCi0kXPL6PDoT?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Student Details</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="contactdetails.html">Contact Info</a> 
</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane active">
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Student Name:</label>
<input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" ng- 
 model="students.name" required>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="age">Age:</label>
  <input type="age" class="form-control" id="age" ng- 
  model="students.age">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same fields and same data in both html?

Comment: no.In contactdetails.html file i have phno and email where as in index.html file i have name and age of a student.